# how to connect gitlab with openProject

Tags: linux, git, gitlab, webhooks, openproject

Hello I have a requirement is it posible to connect somehow gitlab with openproject?

I have seen this https://www.openproject.org/news/57-openproject-github-integration-plugin-released
but not sure if it will help somehow with gitlab

Comment: What exactly does "connect somehow gitlab with openproject" mean? What is your specific requirement?

Comment: @Chris  I don't have the exact requirement of what he really wants is just a feature that he told us we should be using in openproject and since I'm barely touching OP I wanted to know what are the realistic capabilities of the tool... so what are the present capabilities of OP in terms of connecting to gitlab? or at least a simple git will do the job for now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the past, you could connect most git repositories to a project, so you could also connect those on GitLab. However, the git proper integration seems to be [broken for some time](https://www.openproject.org/topics/1166) now.

The [GitHub integration plugin](https://www.openproject.org/news/57-openproject-github-integration-plugin-released) you mentioned will not work with GitLab though, as their web hook APIs will probably differ.

You probably should elaborate your question and put it on one of the [OpenProject boards](https://www.openproject.org/projects/openproject/boards).

Comment: Hi, do you have any idea about nowadays state of this integration, there is not much to google. :(

Comment: [Here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/21928) is the corresponding Issue on Gitlab's side of things and [here](https://community.openproject.com/projects/openproject/work_packages/23673/activity) is the current Wishlist for OP.

Please note [Douwe's comment](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/21928#note_15333508):

"..if you are simply looking to link #123 to the respective issue inside OpenProject. If that's the case, you could also use the 'Custom Issue Tracker' option under Project > Services however, which lets you configure the URLs to use manually."